mysql ORDER BY return order differently
Trying to figure out why mysql's ORDER BY clause can return order differently, e.g.:

The two files are both generated by using mysql on command line with a single command:
mysql mydb -e 'SELECT DISTINCT name FROM my_table ORDER BY name;' > name.lst
but on two different Linux systems, querying the same DB with apparently same mysql/MariaDB:
# Machine 1
$ mysql -V
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.5.25-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper


# Machine 2
$ mysql -V
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.5.25-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

Where should I look next for what's causing the problem please? (Like my LANG? would it matter?)
UPDATE:
Comparing character set / collation variables completely as suggested by Akina revealed where the problem is.
Here is the comparison between two systems https://www.diffchecker.com/DhsN55Wq/

Comparing with the two and consulting with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074492/what-is-the-difference-between-utf8mb4-and-utf8-charsets-in-mysql,
I'm thinking that settings on the right make more sense; what'd you say? How to correct it please? thx.

Unicode Character Sets utf8: An alias for utf8mb3.

mysql> select 'a' < '_' collate 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci';
+----------------------------------------+
| 'a' < '_' collate 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci' |
+----------------------------------------+
|                                      0 |
+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select 'a' < '_' collate 'utf8mb4_general_ci';
+----------------------------------------+
| 'a' < '_' collate 'utf8mb4_general_ci' |
+----------------------------------------+
|                                      1 |
+----------------------------------------+

(similarly for utf8)
